# Avoiding degeneracy in an LP formulation

Tags: linear-programming, degeneracy, perturbation

I assume that "less than or equal to" $\left( \leq \right)$ and "greater than or equal to" $\left( \geq \right)$ constraints avoid degeneracy because each of those has at least one unique slack/surplus variable attached.
So, therefore, I assume that degeneracy can only exist for equality $(=)$ constraints.

And so I am postulating that a good way to avoid degeneracy is then to introduce slack/surplus variables to equality constraints (as perturbations) and then constrain those slack/surplus variables to some small quantity (0.00000001), etc. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 6):

The premise is wrong. Degeneracy occurs when a vertex $x$ of a feasible region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ lies on more than $n$ bounding hyperplanes, or equivalently if more than $n$ constraints (including any sign restrictions) are binding at $x$. This can happen even when all constraints are inequality constraints. Consider a problem with two variables and the constraints $x\ge 0,$ $x_1 + x_2 \le 1$ and $x_1 - x_2 \ge -1.$ The point $(0,1)$ is a vertex of the feasible region and three constraints (both "functional" constraints and $x_1 \ge 0$) are binding there, making it degenerate.